# How to add action to Visual Studio Solution Explorer?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

Please let me know how to add an action into the context-menu of "Solution Explorer" in Visual Studio?

I'd like to add my action into the context-menu of files listed in this explorer (see a screenshot for example), and then be able to launch my application (EXE file) that can get the filename (including its path) as an argument.

I currently use VS2008, however please let me know if that should be different with VS2010 and VS2012.

[image]

THANK YOU

Comment: I think you are writing your own visual studio extension? What have you tried yourself already?

Comment: I haven't tried yet. I'm looking for directions... Thx

Answer (score 1):

Write your own [visual studio Add-In](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42876/Boosting-Developer-Productivity-by-Writing-Extensi) take a look at that link this is good place to start. but its not easy...

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to write a Visual Studio Add-In.

Take a look at the code for the [Xsd2Code](http://xsd2code.codeplex.com/) addin on codeplex. Specifically the [Connect class](http://xsd2code.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/99803#1382412). This addin does something similar to what you want... it adds a context menu option that's available when you right-click on project items (in this case, only enabled for .xsd files).

Also, check out the **Solution Explorer Context Menu** sample within the [Visual Studio 2005 Automation Samples](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9122) download.